# Trouble with image posting and mysql BLOB variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for creating employee and I need to store images in my database (using BLOB MySQL datatype). I use this code and I get an error. Is it about this line?

```
$file=file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
```

what is wrong with this code???

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    $name=mysqli_prep($_POST["name"]);
    $family=mysqli_prep($_POST["family"]);
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $staff_id=$_POST["staff_id"];
    $account_number=$_POST["account_number"];
    $sex=$_POST["sex"];
    $number_of_children=$_POST["number_of_children"];
    $tel=$_POST["tel"];
    $address=$_POST["address"];
    $no=$_POST["no"];
    $working_record=$_POST["working_record"];
    $marital_state=$_POST["marital_state"];
    $employer_id=$_POST["employer_id"];
        $file=file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]); 


    $query  ="INSERT INTO Employee (";
    $query .="Name,Family,ID,Staff_ID,Account_Number,Sex,Number_of_Children,";
    $query .="Tel,Address,No,Working_Record,Marital_State,";
    $query .="Employer_ID,Image)";
    $query .=" VALUES (";
    $query .="'{$name}','{$family}',{$id},{$staff_id},{$account_number},";       
    $query .="'{$sex}',{$number_of_children},{$tel},'{$address}',{$no},";
    $query .="'{$working_record}','{$marital_state}',";
    $query .="{$employer_id},'$file')";        
    $result =mysqli_query($connection, $query);

       if(!$result){   
           $_SESSION["message"] ="There were some errors,fill each 
       section carefully";   
           redirect_to("creat_employee.php");
       }
       else{
           $_SESSION["message"]="filling has been done !";

           redirect_to("creat_employee.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Need the error message. Also are you sure tmp_name is a file name or a byte array of the image?

Comment: @Chuck: yes, tmp_name is temporay file's name where php saved the file.

Comment: Pls provide the exact error message and on which line you get it. It is rather difficult to debug a code if we do not know what error we are looking for... Also, instead of returning `"There were some errors,fill each 
   section carefully"` in case of an error, you could - at least for debugging purposes - return the actual error message.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: unfortunately my code doesn't provide the specific message since I was in a rush.I just put a condition that if there was error,show a message

Comment: I know about the SQL injection.I just wanted to check this uploading matter on the fly

Comment: I used mysqli_error($con) and the error is :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HR� H(pa���_�?����ߓ'?#�IR� HR�XE_�3gΐ��' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the  answer,tried addslashes function (used for sqlinjection) and surprisingly it worked properly